# Adding a space after a special character

Tags: python, regex, string

Im trying to add a space after a special character if there isn't one already in a string.

This is my code

```
import re
line='Hello there! This is Robert. Happy New Year!Are you surprised?Im not.'
for i in re.finditer(r"\?|!|\.", line):
if line[i.end()]!=' ':
    line=line.replace(line[i.end()],line[i.end()]+' ')
```

Expected output:

```
"Hello there! This is Robert. Happy New Year! Are you surprised? Im not."
```

Output from my code:

```
"Hello t here!  This is Robert . Happy New Year!A re you surprised? Im not ."
```

I still haven't figured out why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think your code is not related to result. Because `t` is replaced with `t `. So I suspect you used `t` in pattern in your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'([!?.])(?=\S)', r'\1 ', line)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/aG8RIf/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [!?.]                    any character of: '!', '?', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##HYyxCsIwGIT3PsV1SgoSEOdS3OrioC5iHVr8IYE0CX9SJE8fY@HgbvjuCzlp706lmDV4TmBqrHHUi5Gs9UiamFo8tImoufmFOCmMcwgZV/riSTO3ZyZkvyFuHNhE@gyXFc4nJXYZ@qpVcVskC/lqB/Xu5NBP904cwGI6ovaf65r6dknuu5Qf)**:

```py
import re
line='Hello there! This is Robert. Happy New Year!Are you surprised?Im not.'
line = re.sub(r'([!?.])(?=\S)', r'\1 ', line)
```

**Results**: `Hello there! This is Robert. Happy New Year! Are you surprised? Im not.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression with `re.sub`, with (zero-width) matches being replaced by one space:

```
(?<=[!?.])(?=\S)
```

`(?<=[!?.])` is a *negative lookbehind* that asserts that the string position is preceded by one of the three characters in the given character class, and the *positive lookahead* `(?=\S)` asserts that the current string position is followed by a character other than a whitespace.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sU8Xdh/1)

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you use an alternation for 3 characters `\?|!|\.` that could also be in a single character class `[?!.]`

What you can do is match either one of them, and assert a non whitespace char other than any of those characters after it, in case you have for example `Hi!!`

In the replacement you can use the full match using `\g<0>` followed by a space.

```
[?!.](?=[^?!.\s])
```

**The pattern matches**

- `[?!.]` Match either `!` `.` `?`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `[^?!.\s]` Match a non whitespace char other than `!` `.` `?`
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC33BR/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qbViZO).

**Example**

```
import re

regex = r"[?!.](?=[^?!.\s])"
line = 'Hi!!Hello there! This is Robert. Happy New Year!Are you surprised?Im not.'
result = re.sub(regex, r'\g<0> ', line)

if result:
    print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Hi!! Hello there! This is Robert. Happy New Year! Are you surprised? Im not.
```